# MySQL takes up totall installed memory of 16GB in 24 hours lie period

Tags: mysql

I'm managing a server with the following configurations, and tuned up the MySQL using mysqltuner.pl. However got ended up server getting used up 100% of the installed memory. I seek you advise to rectify this.

Ubuntu Server 18.04
RAM : 16 GB
CPUs: 4
MySQL: 5.7.31

Following is the configuration file of my MySQL server

```
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

innodb_lru_scan_depth = 256

performance_schema=0
#performance-schema-instrument='memory/%=COUNTED'

#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer_size     = 1M
max_allowed_packet  = 24M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 9

tmp_table_size      = 48M
max_heap_table_size = 48M
thread_cache_size   = 12
join_buffer_size    = 4M

wait_timeout        = 120  #set to 10 minutes from 8 hours
interactive_timeout     = 120  #set to 15 minutes from 8 hours

# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover-options  = BACKUP
max_connections         = 275

open_files_limit    = 8192
table_open_cache        = 2750
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 256K
query_cache_size        = 96M
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
query_cache_type    = 1
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
slow_query_log      = 1
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size   = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
```

Mysqltuner.pl output received just now

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.6.4 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering
[[0;32mOK[0m] Logged in using credentials from debian maintenance account.

[[0;34m--[0m] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[[0;32mOK[0m] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log
[[0;32mOK[0m] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[[0;34m--[0m] Status: [0;32m+ARCHIVE [0m[0;32m+BLACKHOLE [0m[0;32m+CSV [0m[0;31m-FEDERATED [0m[0;32m+InnoDB [0m[0;32m+MRG_MYISAM [0m
[[0;34m--[0m] Data in InnoDB tables: 7G (Tables: 228)
[[0;31m!![0m] Total fragmented tables: 63

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[[0;32mOK[0m] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[[0;32mOK[0m] All database users have passwords assigned
[[0;31m!![0m] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations  ---------------------------------------
[[0;34m--[0m] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[[0;34m--[0m] Up for: 18h 41m 49s (21M q [325.215 qps], 246K conn, TX: 58G, RX: 3G)
[[0;34m--[0m] Reads / Writes: 95% / 5%
[[0;34m--[0m] Binary logging is disabled
[[0;34m--[0m] Total buffers: 8.2G global + 4.8M per thread (275 max threads)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Maximum reached memory usage: 9.3G (59.59% of installed RAM)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Maximum possible memory usage: 9.4G (60.43% of installed RAM)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Slow queries: 0% (10K/21M)
[[0;31m!![0m] Highest connection usage: 89%  (247/275)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (1/246569)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Query cache efficiency: 75.8% (15M cached / 20M selects)
[[0;31m!![0m] Query cache prunes per day: 4043524
[[0;32mOK[0m] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (14K temp sorts / 1M sorts)
[[0;31m!![0m] Joins performed without indexes: 1764
[[0;32mOK[0m] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (1K on disk / 126K total)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (4K created / 246K connections)
[[0;31m!![0m] Table cache hit rate: 17% (2K open / 13K opened)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Open file limit used: 0% (39/5K)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (318 immediate / 318 locks)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[[0;31m!![0m] Key buffer used: 18.7% (196K used / 1M cache)
[[0;32mOK[0m] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 1.0M/43.0K
[[0;32mOK[0m] Read Key buffer hit rate: 97.9% (430 cached / 9 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[[0;34m--[0m] InnoDB is enabled.
[[0;32mOK[0m] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 8.0G/7.6G
[[0;32mOK[0m] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 8
[[0;31m!![0m] InnoDB Used buffer: 71.86% (376697 used/ 524224 total)
[[0;32mOK[0m] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (118056700441 hits/ 118056942522 total)
[[0;31m!![0m] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 73.83% (741389 hits/ 1004247 total)
[[0;32mOK[0m] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 262858 writes)

-------- ThreadPool Metrics --------------------------------------------------
[[0;34m--[0m] ThreadPool stat is disabled.

-------- AriaDB Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[[0;34m--[0m] AriaDB is disabled.

-------- TokuDB Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[[0;34m--[0m] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ------------------------------------------------------
[[0;34m--[0m] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[[0;34m--[0m] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[[0;34m--[0m] This is a standalone server..

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce or eliminate persistent connections to reduce connection usage
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64: 
    Beware that open_files_limit (5000) variable 
    should be greater than table_open_cache ( 2357)
Variables to adjust:
    max_connections (> 275)
    wait_timeout (< 120)
    interactive_timeout (< 120)
    query_cache_size (> 96M)
    join_buffer_size (> 4.0M, or always use indexes with joins)
    table_open_cache (> 2357)
```

Following is the present status of the server. I have restated mysql server around 6 hours back having changed wait_timeout & interactive_timeout to 90. However currently the situation seems normal due to low uptime in the server.

I'm running Drupal 7 based news website which averages a daily traffic of 90,000 page visits

[Current resource usage on the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e71pY.png)

In reply to @Wilson Hauck, Yes the server uses SSD as the hard disk. Please refer to the following pastbin link to find the details of B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/YhWP9szmjP/

```
$ ulimit -a

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 63934
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 63934
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited


$ iostat -xm 5 3
Linux 5.3.0-1032-aws (ip-172-31-21-134)         08/25/20        _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          32.44    0.64    1.79    0.54    0.10   64.49

Device            r/s     w/s     rMB/s     wMB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
loop0            0.03    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    1.16    0.00   0.00     1.01     0.00   0.13   0.00
loop1            0.12    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    1.24    0.00   0.00     1.01     0.00   0.13   0.00
loop2            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.82    0.00   0.00     8.64     0.00   1.00   0.00
loop3            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.09    0.00   0.00     1.48     0.00   0.33   0.00
loop4            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     1.00     0.00   1.00   0.00
xvda            50.74   48.87      1.77      1.00     7.64    17.73  13.09  26.62    1.08    3.41   0.10    35.70    20.89   0.86   8.57

qavg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          82.65    0.00    2.06    0.05    0.00   15.23

Device            r/s     w/s     rMB/s     wMB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
loop0            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
loop1            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
loop2            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
loop3            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
loop4            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
xvda             5.00   15.80      0.04      0.20     0.00    12.80   0.00  44.76    0.68    1.18   0.00     8.96    12.66   1.73   3.60


avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          92.67    0.00    2.46    0.10    0.05    4.72

Device            r/s     w/s     rMB/s     wMB/s   rrqm/s   wrqm/s  %rrqm  %wrqm r_await w_await aqu-sz rareq-sz wareq-sz  svctm  %util
loop0            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
loop1            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
loop2            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
loop3            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
loop4            0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00    0.00    0.00   0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00   0.00
xvda             5.80    9.80      0.16      0.09     6.00    11.00  50.85  52.88    1.28    0.69   0.00    27.72     9.39   2.62   4.08
```

[Latest server's resources usage measured using glances tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKWrV.png)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I posted the output of the mysqltuner.pl

Comment: Can you post the output of the tool that shows memory usage?

Comment: This is fairly well tuned for memory usage already, given the level of traffic you appear to be receiving. You probably need a server with more RAM.

Comment: @Halfgaar I posted a screen shot of the current status of the server obtained using glances tool

Comment: Your screenshot shows 6.53G memory free. What is the problem, is your server crashing?

Comment: @Bert Yes and mysql eats up the total memory and server stops responding. memory utilization grows up to 100% once it reaches 24hrs to 36 hrs since the restart of the server. Currently it is 9 hours passed since the last restart of MySQL and now only 4.8 G is free compared to 6.53 G

Comment: You almost certainly need more RAM and you absolutely need more CPU. It is time to upgrade to a larger instance type. You should also consider Drupal-specific performance tuning, as Drupal can be very heavyweight and put a lot of pressure on MySQL. Our sister site [drupal.se] is a good place to ask Drupal-specific questions.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you very much for the advice.

Comment: Your screenshot shows high CPU, but not high Mem.  In addition to what Wilson asked for, get the slowlog (with `long_query_time=1`, not the default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_cache_size=100  # from 12 to reduce overhead of threads_created 18,140 in 4 days
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to allow higher IOPS on your SSD media
read_buffer_size=512K  # from 128K to reduce handler_read_next RPS of 446,320
read_rnd_buffer_size=96K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 19,363
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  from 256 to conserve 50% of CPU cycles used for function
```

You will find these changes reduce CPU busy significantly.

Many more opportunities exist to improve your configuration.  View my profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to improve performance.